# LaTeX: Cannot Create Document

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am just starting out with LaTeX, and trying to create my first document. I am using Mac OS X 10.8.3.

After creating a `hello.tex` file, I then type `latex hello` into the command line. This returns the output below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./hello.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `(.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
```

I've been trying to find a workaround for this, but have been unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is actually quite self-explanatory. However, we cannot really help you without a **minimal, complete example**. Posting the error message alone isn’t enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you've used parentheses instead of curly braces when declaring the document's class. That is, you have something like

```
\documentclass(article)
```

but it should be

```
\documentclass{article}
```

BTW, you really also need to include the content of the file, not just the error message.

Comment: Thank you, I feel foolish. The issue was a ( vs {.